# Is it possible to use an iframe as an 'proxy'?

Tags: html, iframe, proxy

I want to load the contents of an entire webpage in my website. The HTML content is retrieved using cURL.

The title states a `proxy`. That's not really my aim, but that's what it basically is.

Is it somehow possible to load the contents in an `iframe` to display in stead of using a `src` attribute?

```
<iframe class="output">
<?php echo $content; ?>
</iframe>
```

[Example of the HTML](http://wwwinspect.pieterhordijk.com/raw?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iana.org%2Fdomains%2Fexample%2F) I retrieve and [the page with the `iframe`](http://wwwinspect.pieterhordijk.com/output?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iana.org%2Fdomains%2Fexample%2F) I would like to load the contents in.

If it is not possible (what I suspect) what would be another way of doing it (a 'real' frame???).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use php to fwrite the html retrieved to a file and then set that temp file as the src of the iframe.

Or , combine with javascript to post process the html, like:

```js
function callthisonload(){ 

   var iFrame = document.getElementById('youriFrameID');

   iFrame.outerHTML = '<?php echo $curlReponseContents; ?>';

}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I really hope there is another solution.

Comment: **Edit:** Added option that doesnt require writing to file.